# Change DatagridCell Foreground while editing

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

How do I change the Foreground color while editing a Cell of a Datagrid?
The Color should only be changed while editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EditingElementStyle on the column. Like this:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col1" Binding="{Binding myString}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```